# Validating Decimal numbers using validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

I have an `input` element in my form in which the user inputs price for a specific product. To do so he can either put an amount with decimal numbers or he can simply put a price without the decimal numbers.

```
<input type="text" id="product_price" name="product_price" maxlength="10" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter price">
```

```js
$('#addForm').validate({
    rules:{
        product_name: {
            required: true,
        },
        product_price: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        }
    }
})
```

This is what I did however I don't get what I wanted to achieve. I am trying to make it so that a user can put a `number` of length `10` up to `two` decimals. For example, if he enters `1111111111` or `1111111111.11` These both should be valid. What should I do and what be the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex. In JavaScript,

```
if (/^\d{1,10}(\.\d{2})?$/.test(product_price.value))
    // do stuff
```

This regex should match `1`, `46871325`, `18671.68` but not `46812547.178687`.

Btw, you don't need `maxlength` and `step` attributes, just remove them :)

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLhwkbzL/1/)

Comment: won't work for "100." would recommend `/^\d{1,10}\.?\d{0,2}$/`

Comment: @David784 of course it won´t, that´s not a valid decimal number, else he wasn´t asking for numbers you´ve made regex for.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's just me, but I couldn't get the `step` to work reliably. But it appears that validation will allow you to [override the method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.methods/) for number (or any of its other types). So here's what I would probably do:

```
$.validator.methods.number = function(value,e) {
    return this.optional(e) || /^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$/.test(value)
};
```

The regex will verify that at least one number has been entered, optionally followed by a decimal point and up to two additional numbers.

And then remove the step:

```
<input type="text" id="product_price" name="product_price" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter price">
```

Comment: and at the starting i should include the script for additional methods right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. All you should have to change is to add the `$.validator.methods` statement somewhere in your `$(document).ready()`, above your `$('#addForm').validate()`.

Comment: maxlength has been fixed here to 10 .So after that it doesnt show up decimal numbers.Should i remove the `maxlength` attribute?

Comment: can you provide a running snippet or on js fiddle ?

Comment: Here is a fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/5kzh7ykz/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/5kzh7ykz/6/)

Comment: This was close to what i wanted but not complete.Did you see the max length was 10 ?

Comment: max length appeared to be working correctly, by the maxlength attribute of the input. It prohibits more than 10 characters from being entered into that field. Or did you mean 10 decimals in front of the decimal point?